# Is it possible to get the size of external table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I wanted to know whether there is way to discover the size (preferably in bytes but rows can also help) of external table in snowflake?

I'm looking for some metadata, rather then doing something like -
`select count(*) from external_table`

Thanks,

Nir.

Comment: thanks @LukaszSzozda. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function [EXTERNAL_TABLE_FILES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/external_table_files.html):

> This table function can be used to query information about the staged data files included in the metadata for a specified external table.
>
> ```
> +--------------+------------+-----------------------------+
> | Column Name  | Data Type  |         Description         |
> +--------------+------------+-----------------------------+
> | FILE_SIZE    | NUMBER     | Size of the file (in bytes) |
> +--------------+------------+-----------------------------+
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> select *
> from table(information_schema.external_table_files(TABLE_NAME=>'MYTABLE'));
> ```

Comment: How do we get size of the s3 file from querying in snowflake

Comment: @Kar This should be a new question as it is not related External tables. to get file size you can use [`LIST @external_stage_name` command](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/list)